# Drag n Drop for Twitter bootstrap 2.0?

Tags: jquery, gwt, drag-and-drop, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-draggable

I found this slick [drag n drop page](http://bootstrap4gwt.appspot.com/) for Twitter Boostrap. Is this using GWT or purely twitter bootstrap? Does anyone know if there is a plugin to allow drag n drop functionality with Twitter Bootstrap 2.0?

Thanks

Comment: The page basically answers your question, it is using GWT. Bootstrap only styles the app.

Comment: @DavidNguyen Bootstrap also incorporates custom jQuery plugins for various interactions and tools as well. It's not just a collection of styles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bootstrap is essentially just a stylesheet with some javascript modules included in the download.  There's no reason existing drag and drop functionality can't also be used on a page that includes the Bootstrap styles.

Comment: I am down-voting this answer because perhaps the most popular library for drag-drop, jQuery UI w/ the Draggable plugin, does not work with Boostrap's JavaScript libraries. There is a conflict between jQuery UI and Bootstrap's JS plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a build of jQuery UI that is limited to the drag-drop functionality, and, at least with Bootstrap 3 (where I have done this) it is able to coexist.

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, which is vague at best, this answer actually presents a viable solution!! Somehow the stack community has not figured that out. Nonetheless, I exported a custom build of the jqueryui lib as described in this answer and added it to a bootstrap project, tested a sample and done and done. Not to mention it's lightweight :)Thanks @Morris Singer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI can do this, but it is incompatible with Bootstrap. There is a project combining the Bootstrap with jQuery UI called [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) that can be used as a drop-in replacement for Bootstrap in most cases.